# Md5 always same hash when drag&drop in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, drag-and-drop, md5

I have drag&drop event and I would like to hash the filed dragged. I have this:

```
var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
var hashf = CryptoJS.SHA512(file).toString();
console.log("hashf", hashf)
```

But when I drag differents files, "hashf" is always the same string.

https://jsfiddle.net/9rfvnbza/1/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attempting to hash the File object. Hash algorithms expect a string to hash.

When passing the File Object to the `CryptoJS.SHA512()` method, the API attempts to convert the object to a string. That conversion results in `CryptoJS.SHA512()` receiving the same string not matter what File object you send provide it.

The string is `[object File]` - you can replace `file` in your code with that string and discover it is the same hash code you've see all along.

To fix this, retrieve the text from the file first and pass that to the hashing algorithm:

```js
file.text().then((text) => {
  const hashf = CryptoJS.SHA512(text).toString();
  console.log("hashf", hashf);
});
```

If you prefer async/await, you can put it in an IIFE:

```js
(async() => {
  const text = await file.text()
  const hashf = CryptoJS.SHA512(text).toString();
  console.log("hashf", hashf);
})();
```